# How to get HINSTANCE to LoadBitmap from resources

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I would like to load a bitmap using c++ from resources but I have no idea what hInstance is or how to get it. I have read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MFC (you didn't tag your question with MFC but ...) you can use [`AfxGetInstanceHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36z3tfsb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). If you're not using MFC - i.e. you have a standard Winapi implementation), then the instance handle is passed as an argument to your `WinMain` function.

Creating the boilerplate code for a new Win32 Windows application results in the following code, from which you just need to store `hInstance` somewhere handy for later

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_WIN32PROJECT4, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32PROJECT4));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

If you'd rather not do that, and you want the `HINSTANCE` of your exe rather than a DLL, you can also use [`GetModuleHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the same thing.

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

If that's not enough, there is also [`GetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);
```